# switch back and forth between two buffers in emacs like b# in vim

Tags: vim, emacs

I'm new to Emacs and I'm looking for the command that switch between the current and the last switched buffer. The equivalent in vim is `b#`

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: if you haven't seen it already, take a look at [`evil-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/Evil), which is a very good Vim emulation layer for Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

It's `C-x b RET`. It's possible to type a buffer name before the `RET`, but if you don't, it will use the previous buffer.

You can learn this and other basic Emacs commands in the built-in tutorial. To run it, hit `C-h t`.

Comment: @nXqd, you may want to keep around the official reference card for a while : http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf

Comment: There is also `C-x left/right` and with `winner-mode`, you can cycle through window configuration history with `C-c left/right`.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple command. Does the job perfectly well.

command **mode-line-other-buffer** (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘bindings.el’.

Does what b# for vim does, switching back and forth between the last 2 buffers (any kind of buffers)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'mode-line-other-buffer)